# How can i print results in text file

Tags: batch

Hello i have this script to test the network services, The script can scan the ip if any port is open or not and do the iterations attempts of successful and unsuccessful all i want to print these result in a text file in the end ! so i can check how many successful attempts are made. can anyone help me in this plz

```
@echo off

color 2

set /p "$IP= Enter IP Address: "
set /p "$services= Enter Service Name(e.g TELNET, FTP, MSTSC, TFTP): "
set /p "$Port= Enter Port No: "
set /p "$N= Enter Number of Iterations to be performed: "

for /l %%a in (1,1,%$N%) do start %$services% %$IP% %$Port%
@echo %IP%:%servicen%:%port%.%N% >> filename.txt
pause
```

in last i have tried with echo to print result but not working for me

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the `$` sign in the variable names and misspelled the `services` variable:

```
@echo off

color 2

set /p "$IP= Enter IP Address: "
set /p "$services= Enter Service Name(e.g TELNET, FTP, MSTSC, TFTP): "
set /p "$Port= Enter Port No: "
set /p "$N= Enter Number of Iterations to be performed: "

for /l %%a in (1,1,%$N%) do start %$services% %$IP% %$Port%
@echo %$IP%:%$services%:%$Port%.%$N% >> filename.txt
pause
```

Comment: Thanks for the correction , but it only gives a me result like this in a text file : 192.168.0.1:FTP:21.10 what i actually want the results of successful and unsuccessful attempts

Answer (score 0):

Your code can improve, and that's what I did with it, now it captures the inputs, does some checks, and makes it available in variables.

Everyone who writes/works with languages, scripts and things like that, after a while develops a "modus operandi" or "layout styles", I wrote using mine in a "smooth/soft" way, but I understand that it may be difficult to understand/edit/adapt at some point.

So use the comments as much as you want, I will reply when possible and as possible...

Understand that this code is not ready, here are missing the commands where your variables will come into use, after that, the result can be treated in a way to meet ***i actually want the results of successful and unsuccessful attempts***

Without providing us with your commands or the attempts of each one, it is not possible to help you, since each of them has particularities for interacting on the command line via script in [bat](/questions/tagged/bat)/[cmd](/questions/tagged/cmd) and some in [vbs](/questions/tagged/vbs)/[powershell](/questions/tagged/powershell)....

Only a command `start !$IP! !$services! :!$Port!` is not a command that effectively start/performs any action on any IP/port that can be used in any type of services and also making it possible to obtain an output/result that meets:

```all-bat
Successful attempt !$IP!:!$services!:!$Port!.!_Iteract!
Unsuccessful attempt !$IP!:!$services!:!$Port!.!_Iteract!
```

Some will have their outputs in different encodes and within their own environment, where the use of commands alone will not be enough to execute and prove that the results obtained satisfy a success or not....

I left some open `:label` for these so that your command for each service can be added to the script in your future attempts.

```all-bat
@echo off && cd /d "%~dp0"

setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion && color 02



:ip
set _i=<nul & cls & echo\ 
set /p "$IP= Enter IP Address: " || goto=:ip

for /f %%i in ('cmd /u/c echo\"!$IP!"^<nul^|find/v " "^|find "."')do set /a "_i+=1+0"
if !_i! neq 3 echo/The ip address entered is not valid.. && timeout -1 && goto=:ip

echo\.!$IP!|findstr /b \.[0-9]|findstr /v [a-Z] >nul || goto=:ip
for %%p in (!$ip:.=^,!)do for %%i in ("%%~p leq -1","%%~p gtr 255")do <con: ^
     call if %%~i echo/The ip address entered is not valid.. && timeout -1 && goto=:ip
      
set "_IP=Enter IP Address: !$ip!" 
  
  
  
:service
cls & echo\ && echo\!_IP!
set /p "$services= Enter Service Name (e.g TELNET, FTP, MSTSC, TFTP): " || goto=:service
      
for %%i in ("!$services!")do echo\%%~i|findstr /ilb "TELNET FTP MSTSC TFTP" >nul || (
     echo/The service name entered is not valid.. && timeout && goto=:service )
    
for %%s in (TELNET,FTP,MSTSC,TFTP)do if /i "!$services!" == "%%~s" <nul ^
     set "_services=Enter Service Name (e.g TELNET, FTP, MSTSC, TFTP): %%~s" 



:port
cls & echo\ && echo\!_IP! && echo\!_services!
set /p "$Port= Enter Port No: " || goto=:Port

echo\!$Port!|findstr /b [0-9]|findstr /v [a-Z] >nul || <nul ^
     echo/The port number entered is not valid.. && timeout -1 && goto=:port 

for %%I in ("!$Port! geq 00001","!$Port! leq 64738")do <con: ^
     call if %%~I echo/The port number entered is not valid.. && timeout -1 && goto=:port

set "_port=Enter Port No: !$Port!"



:Iteract
cls & echo\ & echo\!_IP! & echo\!_services! & echo\!_port!
set /p "$Iteract=Enter Number of Iterations to be performed: " || goto=:Iteract

echo\!$Iteract!|findstr /b [0-9]|findstr /v [a-Z] >nul || <nul ^
     echo/The Iterations entered is not valid.. && timeout -1 && goto=:Iteract

for %%I in ("!$Iteract! geq 1","!$Iteract! leq 10")do <con: ^
     call if %%~I echo/The Iterations entered is not valid.. && timeout -1 && goto=:Iteract
     
set "_Iteract=Enter Number of Iterations to be performed:  !$Iteract!"



:TELNET
rem :: here you will enter your commands for interacting with your variables for the
rem :: TELNET service and capturing the results

goto=:EOF



:FTP
rem :: here you will enter your commands for interacting with your variables for the 
rem :: FTP service and capturing the results

goto :EOF



:MSTSC
rem :: here you will enter your commands for interacting with your variables for the 
rem :: MSTSC service and capturing the results

goto=:EOF



:TFTP
rem :: here you will enter your commands for interacting with your variables for the 
rem :: TFTP service and capturing the results

goto=:EOF



:run <Just a suggestion for getting output on file>
cls & echo\ & echo\!_IP! & echo\!_services! & echo\!_port! & echo\!_Iteract! 

>.\filename.txt (for /l %%a in (1,1,!$Iteract!)do start "" /b !$services! !_IP! !$Port! >nul && ( 
         echo\Successful attempt !$IP!:!$services!:!$Port!.!_Iteract! !time: =0! !date! ) || ^ 
         echo\Unsuccessful attempt !$IP!:!$services!:!$Port!.%%a 
        )
```